# MYSQL : Copy data of tables from 2 databases. Both database are in different servers(Hosting companies)

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application where I copy data from a  table of database which is in hosting company myhosting.com.

I need to copy this data to another table of a database which is in a hosting company inmotionhosting.com

It is basically copying data from 2 tables which are in two different hosting company.
Both the database are mysql and I have full rights in both the databases.

I know that we can download entire database and upload the database in another hosting company but it does not solve my purpose.

Comment: `I know that we can download entire database and upload the database in another hosting company but it does not solve my purpose.` why is that ?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/, where they could give you the skinny on things like [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) and the other built-in mechanisms many of us devs don't use often.

Answer (score 0):

This should be very easy in PHP. Just make multiple connections ($link1, $link2, etc.) - one to each server. SELECT data from a table in $link1 and INSERT (or UPDATE) it in $link2.

The only catch is that often a hosting company will only, by default, open MySQL port (normally 3306) for the local server. If that is the case, then if your program is running on server A then it will be able to connect to MySQL on server A without a problem but not MySQL on server B. There should be an easy way in the server control panel to open up port 3306 for remote access - if not then you will have to ask the hosting company (one of them) to do that for you.

Comment: I am getting following error                                                         
                                                                                                    
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (00000/1130): Host '168.144.109.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/113081/webspace/httpdocs/AP/hold-check-connection.php on line 4 Failed to connect to MySQL: Host '168.144.109.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: @kiranshiv - That's about what I would expect. You will have to find out the proper way to connect remotely. For example, with my preferred hosting company (ICDSoft): a) the host name for local is "localhost" and remotely it is a full server name (mysql.whatever...com), and b) you have to enable remote access. Hard to guess what it is for myhosting or immotion, but it will be something similar.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Made the necessary changes and added the up address of remote connection.